# Imagemagick issue: convert multi images to a pdf

Tags: php, imagemagick

I converted success multi images (1 img, 2 imgs,..., 17 imgs) to a pdf, but now I have a problem when convert 26 images (200 dpi) to a pdf.

I have 2 sites:

site 1: I converted successfully.

site 2: I failed, but when I change 26 images to 100 dpi, I converted success.

I checked php.ini on 2 site: memory_limit is 256M, max_execution_time = 60

I think problem is php.ini of site 2, but I can't find wrong setting which make convert fail. Please help me.

Comment: Check the logs and compare php.ini files for differences from both sites.

Comment: thanks, but I can't find the issue